# Upgrade from 2.3.5 to 2.4.0 error related to scconnector_google_feed_cl

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.5, magento2.4.0

I'm upgrading Magento 2.3.5 to 2.4.0, but I'm getting this error when trying bin/magento setup:upgrade:

Unable to apply data patch Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateUrlKeyForProducts for module Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite. Original exception message: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'DBNAME.scconnector_google_feed_cl' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = VALUES(`value`)

I already tried to apply this patch, but it did not help: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/29804/files

Also removed three triggers from some media gallery table as somebody suggested and that did not work. Then I removed the Google Shopping Ads module, but I still get the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run composer upgrade?

Comment: @webmaster I ran the "composer self-update". Also ran "composer update" as part of the normal Magento upgrade process.

Answer (score 0):

I exported empty version of scconnector_google_feed_cl table from another installation and imported it into this installation. After that setup:upgrade went ok. I have no idea why this table was removed from the database in the first place by the upgrade process at some point.